# Python/Pandas: Bug with element-wise division resulting in NaN?

Tags: python, debugging, pandas, dataframe, division

### BACKGROUND & WHAT THE DATA LOOKS LIKE:

I have a DataFrame `df` with several columns. For this matter I'm only slicing out the columns of interest and save them in `x`:

`df` is a huge dataframe, where I slice data from like this:

```
In [29]: x = df[['date', 'amount', 'price']][:25]
```

Just as an info what `x` looks like, see this:

```
In [30]: x
Out[28]:
     date      amount  price
0  2000-11-01       3     57
1  2000-11-01       2     48
2  2000-11-01       1    135
3  2000-11-01       1     24
4  2000-11-01       2    170
5  2000-11-01       1     46
6  2000-11-01       1     28
7  2000-11-01       1     55
8  2000-11-01       1     90
9  2000-11-01       1     20
10 2000-11-01       1    109
11 2000-11-01       1     25
12 2000-11-01       1    129
13 2000-11-01       1     19
14 2000-11-01       1     19
15 2000-11-01       1    168
16 2000-11-01       1     19
17 2000-11-01       1     29
18 2000-11-01       2     48
19 2000-11-01       1     29
20 2000-11-01       1     98
21 2000-11-01       2     58
22 2000-11-01       1     24
23 2000-11-01       2     56
24 2000-11-01       1     86

In [31]: x.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 25 entries, 0 to 24
Data columns (total 3 columns):
date      25 non-null datetime64[ns]
amount    25 non-null int64
price     25 non-null int64
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), int64(2)
```

### WHAT I WANT:

Now I want a new column that contains the price per single item. This is:

- When amount == 1 -> It's the same value as the `price` in that row
- When amount > 1 -> It's `price/amount` of that row

I tried it using boolean indexing:

```
In [32]: x['price1'] = x['price'] # make a full copy of the column

In [33]: rows = x['amount'] > 1

In [34]: x['price1'][rows] = x['price1'][rows] / x['amount'][rows] # change rows where amount>1
```

This works for *small* datasets `x`. 
The output is as follows:

```
In [54]: x
Out[54]:
         date  amount  price  price1
0  2000-11-01       3     57      19
1  2000-11-01       2     48      24
2  2000-11-01       1    135     135
3  2000-11-01       1     24      24
4  2000-11-01       2    170      85
5  2000-11-01       1     46      46
6  2000-11-01       1     28      28
7  2000-11-01       1     55      55
8  2000-11-01       1     90      90
9  2000-11-01       1     20      20
10 2000-11-01       1    109     109
11 2000-11-01       1     25      25
12 2000-11-01       1    129     129
13 2000-11-01       1     19      19
14 2000-11-01       1     19      19
15 2000-11-01       1    168     168
16 2000-11-01       1     19      19
17 2000-11-01       1     29      29
18 2000-11-01       2     48      24
19 2000-11-01       1     29      29
20 2000-11-01       1     98      98
21 2000-11-01       2     58      29
22 2000-11-01       1     24      24
23 2000-11-01       2     56      28
24 2000-11-01       1     86      86
```

### PROBLEM:

When I'm slicing out a bigger range of `df`, with this full code:

```
x = df[['date', 'amount', 'price']][:100]
x['price1'] = x['price']
rows = x['amount'] > 1
x['price1'][rows] = x['price'][rows] / x['amount'][rows]
```

then I'm getting NaN for some divisions:

```
In [113]: x                         
Out[113]:                           
         date  amount  price  price1
0  2000-11-01       3     57      19 <<
1  2000-11-01       2     48      24 <<
2  2000-11-01       1    135     135
3  2000-11-01       1     24      24
4  2000-11-01       2    170     NaN 
5  2000-11-01       1     46      46
6  2000-11-01       1     28      28
7  2000-11-01       1     55      55
8  2000-11-01       1     90      90
9  2000-11-01       1     20      20
10 2000-11-01       1    109     109
11 2000-11-01       1     25      25
12 2000-11-01       1    129     129
13 2000-11-01       1     19      19
14 2000-11-01       1     19      19
15 2000-11-01       1    168     168
16 2000-11-01       1     19      19
17 2000-11-01       1     29      29
18 2000-11-01       2     48     NaN
19 2000-11-01       1     29      29
20 2000-11-01       1     98      98
21 2000-11-01       2     58      85 <<
22 2000-11-01       1     24      24
23 2000-11-01       2     56     NaN
24 2000-11-01       1     86      86
25 2000-11-01       1    145     145
26 2000-11-01       1     29      29
27 2000-11-01      12    434     NaN
28 2000-11-01       1     46      46
29 2000-11-01       1     52      52
..        ...     ...    ...     ...
70 2000-11-01       1     38      38
71 2000-11-01       1     80      80
72 2000-11-01       1     79      79
73 2000-11-01       2    140      24 <<
74 2000-11-01       1     38      38
75 2000-11-01       1     40      40
76 2000-11-01       3     78     NaN
77 2000-11-01       2    104     NaN
78 2000-11-01       2    130      29 <<
79 2000-11-01       1     96      96
80 2000-11-01       1     42      42
81 2000-11-01       1    109     109
82 2000-11-01       1     89      89
83 2000-11-01       1     26      26
84 2000-11-01       1     49      49
85 2000-11-01       1    135     135
86 2000-11-01       1     38      38
87 2000-11-01       1     29      29
88 2000-11-01       2     46     NaN
89 2000-11-01       1     89      89
90 2000-11-01       1     25      25
91 2000-11-01       2    118      28 <<
92 2000-11-01       1     85      85
93 2000-11-01       1     52      52
94 2000-11-01       1     42      42
95 2000-11-01       2     84     NaN
96 2000-11-01       1     18      18
97 2000-11-01       1     28      28
98 2000-11-01       1     85      85
99 2000-11-01       1    102     102                                        
[100 rows x 4 columns]
```

strange enough, some divisions work (marked with `<<`).
Any ideas what could be going on wrongly?
Thanks

### MORE INSIGHT INTO A POSSIBLE "BUG"?

I tried a little bit more and when I'm converting the new `price1`-column to `float64` before the division, it seems to work. For me, this seems like a bug. I can even convert this back to `int64` after division and the results are fine with it. I don't know why it works on small slices (i.e. when I `do x = df[...][:25]`) correctly!?

```
x = df[['date', 'amount', 'price']][:100]
x['price1'] = x['price'].astype(float64)
rows = x['amount'] > 1
x['price1'][rows] = (x['price1'][rows] / x['amount'][rows]).astype(int64)
x
```

gives:

```
In [146]: x = df[['date', 'amount', 'price']][:100]

In [147]: x['price1'] = x['price'].astype(float64)

In [148]: rows = x['amount'] > 1

In [149]: x['price1'][rows] = (x['price1'][rows] / x['amount'][rows]).astype(int64)

In [150]: x
Out[150]:
         date  amount  price  price1
0  2000-11-01       3     57      19
1  2000-11-01       2     48      24
2  2000-11-01       1    135     135
3  2000-11-01       1     24      24
4  2000-11-01       2    170      85
5  2000-11-01       1     46      46
6  2000-11-01       1     28      28
7  2000-11-01       1     55      55
8  2000-11-01       1     90      90
9  2000-11-01       1     20      20
10 2000-11-01       1    109     109
11 2000-11-01       1     25      25
12 2000-11-01       1    129     129
13 2000-11-01       1     19      19
14 2000-11-01       1     19      19
15 2000-11-01       1    168     168
16 2000-11-01       1     19      19
17 2000-11-01       1     29      29
18 2000-11-01       2     48      24
19 2000-11-01       1     29      29
20 2000-11-01       1     98      98
21 2000-11-01       2     58      29
22 2000-11-01       1     24      24
23 2000-11-01       2     56      28
24 2000-11-01       1     86      86
25 2000-11-01       1    145     145
26 2000-11-01       1     29      29
27 2000-11-01      12    434      36
28 2000-11-01       1     46      46
29 2000-11-01       1     52      52
..        ...     ...    ...     ...
70 2000-11-01       1     38      38
71 2000-11-01       1     80      80
72 2000-11-01       1     79      79
73 2000-11-01       2    140      70
74 2000-11-01       1     38      38
75 2000-11-01       1     40      40
76 2000-11-01       3     78      26
77 2000-11-01       2    104      52
78 2000-11-01       2    130      65
79 2000-11-01       1     96      96
80 2000-11-01       1     42      42
81 2000-11-01       1    109     109
82 2000-11-01       1     89      89
83 2000-11-01       1     26      26
84 2000-11-01       1     49      49
85 2000-11-01       1    135     135
86 2000-11-01       1     38      38
87 2000-11-01       1     29      29
88 2000-11-01       2     46      23
89 2000-11-01       1     89      89
90 2000-11-01       1     25      25
91 2000-11-01       2    118      59
92 2000-11-01       1     85      85
93 2000-11-01       1     52      52
94 2000-11-01       1     42      42
95 2000-11-01       2     84      42
96 2000-11-01       1     18      18
97 2000-11-01       1     28      28
98 2000-11-01       1     85      85
99 2000-11-01       1    102     102

[100 rows x 4 columns]
```

Comment: You are doing chained assignment which is wrong, does it work if you do this `x.loc[rows,'price1']= x.loc[rows, 'price'] / x.loc[rows, 'amount']` see the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy)

Comment: In fact you should be able to simplify it further: `x.loc[rows,'price1']= x['price'] / x['amount']` it should align corretly without the mask on the rhs

Comment: Actually, I could even leave out the `rows` completely, as division by `1` would still yield the same price. But probably more expensive regarding performance. Thanks about the chained assigments, Ill shortly look into it. But when I understand the docs corectly, the assigment shouldnt work at all, but it does for small datasets and I don't know why.

Comment: No it may work, the problem is the underlying numpy behaviour yields unexpected behaviour, in 0.13.1 (maybe 0.13.0) it should display a warning when you do this kind of thing, you should always use `.loc` when you assigning unless you cannot

Comment: I'd try with and without the mask to see if it makes a performance difference, you'd be surprised with how premature optimisation does not match reality

Comment: Based on your sample dataset multiplied to create a 25000 row dataframe, using the mask and then assigning took `2.54 ms`, without the mask and just assigning straight takes `950 us` so I'd check the performance at your end using the real dataset

Comment: Okay thanks, yeah I'm using 0.14 currently and it's not displaying a warning at all. I'm still surprised on how it works on a big dataset when converting to float64 before dividing. I know now that using `loc` is better to use anyhow but still... as a new user without the insight into all functionalities, this might be very very confusing (as it was for me) that it works for some number and for some not. So either don't offer the possibility of chain assignment at all or, when offering it, fix it so that it works correctly as expected I'd say.

Comment: Maybe you should post your comment as answer ;-) I can vote for it and accpept it then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing chained assignment which you shouldn't do as it sometimes doesn't work which is what you are observing: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy

moreover you should always use `.loc` if possible, if we compare the performance between using a mask and without a mask we can see that for a 25000 row dataframe based on your sample data it is faster without the mask:

```
In [17]:

%%timeit
x = df[['date', 'amount', 'price']][:100]
x['price1'] = x['price']
rows = x['amount'] > 1
x.loc[rows,'price1']= x['price'] / x['amount']
100 loops, best of 3: 2.54 ms per loop

In [19]:   
%timeit x.loc[rows,'price1']= x['price'] / x['amount']
1000 loops, best of 3: 950 µs per loop
```

Your original code:

```
In [23]:

%%timeit
x = df[['date', 'amount', 'price']][:100]
x['price1'] = x['price'].astype(float64)
rows = x['amount'] > 1
x['price1'][rows] = (x['price1'][rows] / x['amount'][rows]).astype(int64)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.48 ms per loop
```

so you see that dividing on the whole dataframe is faster than selecting the first 100 rows, and then masking and then dividing

Comment: Shouldn't the first timeit-code contain a mask on the rhs? Just for users who see this later...

Comment: @tim sorry is my updated edit what you are asking for?